# Install a package manually -Debian

Tags: cron, package-management, debian-installer

I am working on a customized Linux Debian (Debian 4.9.2-10) server.

I would like to install crontab, which is not installed in the system neither its letting me configure it using the apt or dpkg commands.

I have been given a hint to download the package in my desktop and which I extracted like this:

```
$ wget http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/pool/main/c/cron/cron_3.0pl1-127+deb8u1_amd64.deb
$ mkdir cron
$ dpkg -x cron_3.0pl1-127+deb8u1_amd64.deb ./cron
```

And then move the cron folder via SCP in the targeted server, which I have done and now the folder cron/ is at the home_folder of the server.

Now I would like to configure the cron/, how am I supposed to move forward to install the cron package now considering the apt/dpkg isn't working.

Comment: It is disabled from the maintainer, he gave me a hint to manually install it: and now im in vain that what else or how to configure the crontab.
I have everything on the server to configure the crontab, its just that I have to place the directories from cron folder to the specific folders manually.. below are the files in cron folder: 
etc, var, usr, lib

Comment: idk the reason that why its disabled by the maintainer but this is the situation I am in at the moment..
so do we have any way to configure it manually ?

Comment: ok.. so the only setup I had to done is to copy the cron folder's content to the "/" and thats it.

Comment: let me know how do i delete this post so that you all cannot be bothered.

Comment: this is what exactly what my question was that I didn't know there was any equivalent of: apt install cron as well.

Comment: I'm confused about the situation; if it's not installed and "the system isn't letting you configure it" then are you sure you should be installing it? Is there a system administrator who can install it normally? Who's giving you this advice to download the cron package to your desktop?

Comment: yes Im sure to installing it as I was informed by the admin, so don't worry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to install crontab, which is not installed in the system neither its letting me configure it using the apt or dpkg commands.

If `apt` and `dpkg` aren’t working, that should really be fixed — it will cause issues in the future.

Anyway, if you really want to install `cron` manually, you need to replicate what `dpkg` does when installing a package.

```
cd $TMP
wget http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/pool/main/c/cron/cron_3.0pl1-127+deb8u1_amd64.deb
dpkg -x cron_3.0pl1-127+deb8u1_amd64.deb cron-files
dpkg -e cron_3.0pl1-127+deb8u1_amd64.deb cron-control
```

will download the package and extract boths its contents and its control files. The next steps are to run the appropriate [maintainer scripts](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ap-flowcharts.html) and copy the contents to the right place; I’m assuming `cron` isn’t already installed. As root:

```
cron-control/preinst install
cp -a cron-files/* /
cron-control/postinst configure
```

This ensures that the files are installed, and the package is configured.

The only missing step now is to let `dpkg` know that the package is installed. That currently involves editing `/var/lib/dpkg/status`, but since `dpkg` isn’t working, I wouldn’t want to risk breaking it further.

Comment: Thats what the actually answered my query, couldn't give you a thumbs up as I do not have the enough reputation to mark it answered.